# Sending data from one pod to another pod running specifically on the same host (DaemonSet)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, datadog

I have an agent (datadog agent but could be something else) running on all the nodes of my cluster, deployed through a DaemonSet. This agent is collecting diverse metrics about the host: cpu and memory usage, IO, which containers are running.

It can also collect custom metrics, by listening on a specific port 1234.

How can I send data from a pod to the instance of the agent running on the same node than the pod?
If I use a Kubernetes service the calls to send the metric will be load balanced across all my agents and I'll lose the correlation between the pod emitting the metric and the host it's running on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the exact same setup, `dd-agent` running as a DaemonSet in my kubernetes cluster. Using the same port mapping you commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855220/sending-data-from-one-pod-to-another-pod-running-specifically-on-the-same-host#comment76761846_44857071), you can just send metrics to the hostname of the node an application is running on.

You can add the node name to the pods environment using the downward api in your pod spec:

```
env:
- name: NODE_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: spec.nodeName
```

Then, you can just open an UDP connection to `${NODE_NAME}:8125` to connect to the datadog agent.

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing

Comment: Please do cache the DNS resolution of your NODE_NAME otherwise your Statsd metrics will exhaust your kubedns pretty fast

Comment: @MarkvanStraten As Andy Shinn indicated below, for kubernetes >=1.7 you can access directly the host IP.

Answer (score 3):

Some preliminary Google searching lands me on https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/42717 by way of https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24657. It looks like the pull request was merged in time to be in Kubernetes 1.7. This should mean that you can use the Downward API to expose `status.hostIP` as an environment variable (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) or a file in a volume (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/). Your application would then need to read the environment variable or file to get the value of the actual host IP address.

Comment: Ok that helps but then how can I use this IP? I manage to ping the IP but the daemon doesn't seem to respond, I think it might be an issue with the way I expose the port.
In my pod spec I put:

ports:

          - containerPort: 8125

            hostPort: 8125

            name: dogstatsdport

            protocol: UDP

Comment: Do you happen to know what networking implementation you are using? It sounds like you might be running into https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23920. Per one comment, you may be able to run the DaemonSet with `hostNetwork: true` as a workaround. But this could have other undesirable effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you agent is written by yourself, you can open and listen on a Unix domain socket and let the other pod send data through it.

If not, you can write a small data proxy that listens on a Unix socket for data. On the other end, by sharing a pod with the daemon, you can easily send data to the local container

Comment: They are using dogstatsd, a statsd compatible metrics proxy for Datadog: http://docs.datadoghq.com/guides/dogstatsd/. They could expose a service for dogstatsd and have their application Pod connect to the service. But they specifically want to connect their Pod to the dogstatsd DaemonSet running on the same host. If they use a service, the connection to dogstatsd could be to any host in the DaemonSet, which is what they want to avoid.

Comment: I think you can still write a small proxy for data forwarding. The proxy can share a pod with datadogd and expose a Unix domain at the same time.